# How can i create a database user in sql with same name as sql user?

Tags: sql-server

I have a user under SQL Server -> Security-> Logins as 'testuser'.

I create a database , TestDB and attempt to create a user in the TestDB with name 'testuser', but get the following error :

> Msg 15063, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
> The login already has an account under a different user name.

> Msg 15410, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_addrolemember, Line 35 [Batch Start Line 0]
> User or role 'testuser' does not exist in this database.

This is the create script I use:

```
USE [TestDB] 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT loginname 
               FROM master.dbo.syslogins 
               WHERE name = 'testuser')  
BEGIN
    CREATE LOGIN [testuser] 
        WITH PASSWORD = 'testpassword', 
             DEFAULT_DATABASE = TestDB, 
             DEFAULT_LANGUAGE = [us_english], 
             CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF,  
             CHECK_POLICY = OFF  
END

USE TestDB; 

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.database_principals WHERE name = 'testuser') 
BEGIN
    CREATE USER [testuser] FOR LOGIN [testuser] 
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [dbo] 
END

EXEC sys.sp_addrolemember 
     @rolename = N'db_owner', @membername = N'testuser'
```

I assume I should be able to create this user as it is in the database level ?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear , you already have a username ( which can be anything ) in TestDB database which is linked to the same Login name , so you can't make multiple user under one login.

to find out what is that username you can use query below:

```
USE TestDB
Select u.name , loginname
from sys.syslogins l
inner join sys.sysusers u
on l.sid = u.sid
where loginname = 'testuser'
```